# Android manifest, install error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, manifest

I have INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error when trying to install .apk.

```
  <intent-filter>
    <data scheme="myurlscheme" />
    <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  </intent-filter>
```

If I remove it, everything is fine (except I can't open my app by the url :)
Here is my activity code:

```
 <activity android:name="com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
  <intent-filter>
    <data scheme="myurlscheme" />
    <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What can be wrong with it? It works for many of android devices with OS > 2.2. Except only one device I'm talking about

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 <activity android:name="com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
  <intent-filter>
    <data scheme="myurlscheme" />
    <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To

```
<activity android:name="com.prime31.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <data scheme="myurlscheme" />
    <action name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to declared correct package name(should start from small letter) Please share whole android manifest to understand

Comment: Nope, still INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name="packagename.Activity"
            android:exported="true"
           >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="abc" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

             </intent-filter>


        </activity>
```

you can remove `<data android:scheme="abc" />` from second `<intent-filter>` tag. This is running code, it may help you.

Comment: Didnt help, actually, if I remove  all from the second intent except <data android:scheme="abc" /> then it works fine

Comment: @Zura the syntax and format are right. May be there is some other problem in your code.